# Unable to view Form page in CodeIgniter facing Error

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

This is my **home.php** file in this controller I am facing Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError:
I have also attached a screenshot, In this screenshot error mentioned, You can easily understand the error through this screenshot, I am newbie in CodeIgniter.
[[image]
I upload only my controller related file.

```
<?php

class home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('select');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html'));
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'session'));
    }

    function records() {
        $ytl['dta'] = $this->users->datas();
        //$this->load->view('info',$ytl);
        //echo "<pre>controller";print_r($ytl);
    }

    function primezone() {
        $ytl['dta'] = $this->users->datas();
        echo "<pre>controller";
        print_r($ytl);
    }

    function form($id) {
        //die($id);
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            //echo"<pre>";print_r( $this->input->post());die;
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required|min_length[5]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required|callback_check_picture[lname]');

            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'required|callback_valid_phone_number[mobile]');

            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<h1 class="error">', '</h1>');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                $data = [

                    'fname'   => $this->input->post('fname'),
                    'lname'   => $this->input->post('lname'),
                    'email'   => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'mobile'  => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                    'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
                ];
                if (empty($id)) {
                    $ytl = $this->select->insertdata($data);

                } else {
                    $ytl = $this->select->updatedata($data, $id);
                }
                if ($ytl) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Added.');
                    redirect('home');
                }
            } else {
                //$this->load->view('form');
            }
        }
        $ytl['dta'] = $this->select->getDataById($id);
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($ytl);die;
        $this->load->view('form', $ytl);
    }

    public function check_picture($a) {
        if ( ! is_numeric($a)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_picture', 'Please enter only char value');

            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function valid_phone_number($value) {
        $value = strlen($value);
        //echo $value;die;
        if ($value == 10) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_phone_number', 'Mobile number not in range'); //{10} 

            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        //load the database  
        //$this->load->database();  
        //load the model  
        $this->load->model('select');
        //load the method of model  
        $data['h'] = $this->select->select();
        //return the data in view  
        $this->load->view('fetch_view', $data);
    }

    public function delete() {
        $this->load->model('select');
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        if ($this->select->deleteuser($id)) {
            $data['data'] = $this->select->getuser();
            $this->load->view('fetch_view', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need pass `$id` in url or assign `public function form($id=null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have mention is normally came when there is mismatch in `param` mention in `function` and the passing ones.

According to your code
`public function form($id)` 
`$id` is required and you are not passing that.

So change your code to

```
public function form($id=null)
```

Comment: Ok sir its Working but I am unable to understand I am using $id many places and if I will do null to my $id so they effect on my code

Comment: Glad to know that it's working. If you pass id in url then it will overwrite the the null.

Answer (score 0):

Set default id value in your controller function like

```
function form($id = null){
....
}
```